# Is it worth asking a question that I have struggled a lot with?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm a very low grade programmer and if you look at my questions you will see that they are extremely basic. If I have struggled over a question for a very very long time (but ultimately sorted it out) is it worth me posting it anyway for any similarly poor programmer to benefit from in the future?

Comment: It's not a matter of how simple or basic your questions are here -- the big factor is quality, effort, and value. Make sure you've researched your problem and include that research in your question. A big problem with foundational or basic questions is that they've probably been asked dozens of times before on this network alone. So there is a bit of an onus on you to show that none of the previous questions cover your own. It should also be a valuable question that isn't too localized, and also has the potential to help others in the future.

Comment: The question is worthwhile if: 1) you've done your requisite research for a solution and show the fruits of your efforts in your question, 2) you ask a well presented question, both in code and in explanation, one that is easy to understand and easy to answer.

Comment: One thing you may find helpful when doing research about whether a question has already been asked and answered (or helpful for just using SO, for that matter) is this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching.  It covers how to search using more advanced/focused search parameters, rather than just searching using simple unqualified text strings.

Comment: Follow up to my previous comment (too late to edit further): you may have already been aware of the help page for search, I was not.  I only recently became aware of it by stumbling across it in an answer given here in meta - it's not exactly prominent on the tour page or the help center.  Believe me, I tried finding help on SO search before (search SO for things like "how to search", "stackoverflow advanced search" without advanced qualifiers - your search results will basically be everything in Knuth, Volume 3, and then some).

Comment: You sound like a sad puppy! Don't be hating on yourself! You aren't 'low-grade' and neither are your compatriots, you're a 'beginner' or 'novice' programmer! Judging by you're profile a good term would be 'dabbling.'

Comment: I think I didn't write this question well in the first instance. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood I didn't realise that describing myself as a low-grade programmer would be thought of in this way. I've used a bit of coding off and on for years, always forget how to do half of it between uses and the next time I have to do something, generally I need to use a new language and struggle and struggle with trying to get it to do anything while other people seem to be able to pick up programming languages much more easily. I've come to the conclusion that I am not gifted at programming and I'm OK with that.

Comment: Maybe you're simply not "sticking with it" enough to overcome the initial hump, which is very real, for everyone. If you're just doing it "off and on", you may never progress enough to become proficient and in-between you're just sliding back down the hill. That's very human, for almost any task. I've added a bit of rambling about that to my answer below...

Comment: @deceze I don't really get this: do you go out of your way to do programming - either I have something that I need to do or I do not. Would you recommend going out of my way to do programming tasks? It's certainly an interesting idea but why would I take up something I find soul crushing as a hobby?

Comment: Let's put it this way: I started programming as a hobby when I was a kid and dabbled in it more badly than anything else until my early 20s, at which point I was thrown in at the deep end by getting a job as a developer. Only after sticking with that for a couple of years did things finally click together. In hindsight, I didn't even know how much I didn't know those first many years.

Comment: I think it does take a certain type of personality to stick out the soul crushing part willingly when you could be doing other things. That, or you're simply forced to stick it out by being in a job. Either way, if you manage to get through that rough patch, it may suddenly start picking up and become delightful for you. Maybe it's just the rough start that you're struggling with, not programming as such. But that's ultimately your call...

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User you sound like you're coming at things from a really terrible position. You say "I've come to the conclusion that I am not gifted at programming and I'm OK with that". No one is gifted at programming. We've all had to spend many, _many_ hours tackling difficult problems. I've would never call any of the challenges I've faced "soul-crushing" though. But even if they felt like it at the time, the great pleasure I felt from solving them in the end is always more than worth it. Moral of the story: find pleasure in what you do and accept that there is always more to learn.

Comment: @lealand That's nice advice but to follow it I would need to stop programming and right now that is not an option. Thank you for your concern nonetheless. Maybe, hopefully at some point in the future I'll be able to make that leap. I have never found any pleasure in programming and I can't even imagine what it looks like. I draw no pleasure from getting it working: it is something that I unfortunately have to do.

Comment: If you've never looked at your own code and thought *"man, this is really awesome, it's so great the way this works"*... then yeah, maybe programming really isn't for you. For some people it's the finished product that excites them, and for some it's the code itself that they can find pleasure in. If you have neither, then maybe your primary field where you'll find pleasure is indeed elsewhere.

Comment: @deceze I'm going to tell myself that I just haven't written something that good yet. I have I suppose been grateful that something is finally working that it is off my back and producing results but really I just feel anger and resent the time it has taken from my life. Basically, you are right and I should try to change my life so that I don't have to program. It's a good medium term goal.

Comment: I don't know what kind of development you do exactly, but I do believe that certain types of projects can be very frustrating these days. 20 years ago, things were somewhat more simple. Computers couldn't really do a lot, you had to program pretty close to the metal, pushing bits and bytes around. That was more "geeky", but also less complex in some ways. These days most devs work with very high level code, like plugging together stuff in WinForms and .NET. There's decades of abstractions and work below all that, which can make it very abstract and opaque to work with.

Comment: Programming is incidental - it is not the core of my work but takes a lot of my time: MATLAB, Igor, Bash, fortran, c++... It's very chaotic, I'm a beginner trying to do all manner of things from doing some medium-tough data analysis to trying to do basic output stuff to understand my results all the way through to fiddling around in the bowels of some dragonish monster of code like a cloud model.

Comment: Yeah, if you're just using programming as a means to an end which you're much more interested in than the programming itself, I can see how that can be very frustrating. In that case, concentrating on your actual speciality and letting programmers deal with the programming may be more fruitful. However, especially in the data analysis world you seem to live in, programmatic analysis is often your main tool in your work, no? Getting to grips with it rather sooner than later may be more beneficial to your work than trying to get away from it. Just my 3000-feet-away perspective though... ;)

Comment: @deceze Thanks for taking the time to help me think this through. Think I've dug myself into a bit of a rut, this conversation has sort of helped with that.

Comment: Just check all the questions I asked, enriched by links, ideas, failed attempts. You'll see the answer is *Nope*. Even if you get an answer on such question it usually does not really solve the problem.

Comment: Hope you've been okay @Reluctant_Linux_User. Sounds like you were going through a tough spot and I hope things are better now.

Comment: @lealand I'm hoping things will be better in a few months. Honestly right now they aren't and I'm really not enjoying life or coping very well. I'm a mess but I'm still clinging on somehow.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get this out first:

Precondition: **make sure your super basic question hasn't already been answered.**

That's likely the most primary concern with basic questions, that they've already popped up many times and have already been answered multiple times. We do not need yet another copy of the same topic.

The same applies if it turned out to be a problem answered relatively trivially by reading the manual. If the manual, by which I mean easily accessible documentation of whatever technology you're using, clearly spells out the solution if you just bothered to read it, then we don't really need it on SO either.

If all of the above does not apply, and you have a problem to which the answer is genuinely not obvious, and would take anyone of a similar skill set a long time to research regardless of where they started, then you may just have a good question on your hands. Especially if you've already found the answer yourself, you're more than welcome to document it on SO by posting a self-answered question.

You should present your research efforts with the question to make a good case for why this question needs to be asked. E.g., *"in the manual here it states X, but that's only half the solution"* or *"the compiler outputs Y, but this is misleading because..."*.

---

Do consider that programming *is* a struggle at first for quite a while. Most people have a huge hump to overcome initially. Remembering all the syntax, figuring out the obscure terminology, getting to grips with even the most basic concepts, training your brain in thinking like the machine does, searching everywhere for functions and libraries that do what you want, fighting with obscure and indecipherable error messages...

It can take many years to get through this uphill battle. Only after you have accumulated a bunch of knowledge in a number of different topics and things start to "click" will it usually get easier. After the syntax has become second nature, when you have memorised enough function calls to cover your everyday use, when you've become familiar with a number of standard solutions and design patterns.

There are more questions than answers during this initial struggling period. However, this does not mean that they all make good questions. Sometimes it's only your personal development which is in the way, because the right concepts haven't yet clicked for you. This may be completely different for other people which may have approached their studies in a more structured manner than you did, e.g. through a university course.

Just consider this when thinking of creating a question. Struggling through a certain problem to then find the solution may simply be the path everyone has to take to understand the solution. Maybe there is no shortcut that you can offer by posting an answer, or that shortcut would lessen the learning experience, because there are important things to discover during the journey. If you're presenting the answer on a silver platter, make sure it contains all the important points that you took away from the journey.

Comment: Seriously, we don't mind "simple" questions. It's questions that don't specify **why** they are asking the question that upset the community

Comment: I really like this answer, especially this: `It can take many years to get through this uphill battle. Only after you have accumulated a bunch of knowledge in a number of different topics and things start to "click" will it usually get easier.`

Comment: My first contact with programming was a university course and the only reason I do any programming now is because of a different university course. ;) Apart from that there's some interesting advice here.

Comment: @Reluctant Maybe your first contact was *too structured* then, not enough play. ;)

Comment: "The same applies if it turned out to be a problem answered relatively trivially by reading the manual." I would clarify that barrier somewhat. Some manuals can be huge, and sometimes *finding* the right part of the manual can be painful. If the "manual" is short *and* easy to read *and* a decent Google search fairly readily turns up the right page, then I would agree. If it takes more than 10 minutes of scouring through stuff or the manual is just a complete pain to use, I'd say go ahead and post, especially if it's something you use a lot. It will help other Googlers.

Comment: An expert programmer in one language is going to get caught out by the most ridiculous gotchas in another. Equivalence testing is one of my favourites (e.g. does your language use `if a = b` or `if a == b` or `if a eq b` )

Comment: @Sobrique Don't forget javascript's famous "if (a === b)" (don't use double-equals, it looks like it works, except when sometimes it doesn't! I love that one.)